# How to change the order of Databricks widgets?

Tags: widget, databricks

I have many Databricks widgets, but I cannot change their orders. Automatically, Databricks sorts the widgets alphabetically. However, I want to sort them manually based on their categories. I know that I can use numbers or letters, but this is not the best option for end-users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is supported, at least in Databricks Premium.

Once you create some widgets,

```
dbutils.widgets.text('a_widget','a test')
dbutils.widgets.text('b_widget','another test')
```

You should see the widget bar appear, and there is an edit icon to the right.

[image: A notebook with two Databricks Widgets, one called 'a_widget' and the other 'b_widget'. On the right, the Widget edit button is circled.]

This will allow you to drag/drop (also, resize!) the widgets in the order you choose.

[image: widget b is now before widget a.]

You can see here, 'b_widget' is now before, 'a_widget'. You can click the check mark to confirm your changes.